# How can I detect the WAN IP address assigned to a non-default gateway?

Tags: ssh, routing, internet-connection, ubuntu-server

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server which has access to to two gateways to the internet. (192.168.15.1 & 192.168.15.250)

15.1 has significant bandwidth but does not allow any port forwarding from the wider world. 15.250 will allow port forwarding.

I want to use dynamic DNS to ssh into this machine so naturally I need to use 15.250 for this purpose, but i want applications to by default go through the high-bandwidth connection.

I can update my Dynamic DNS through script, but it relies on a curl request to http://ident.me or http://icanhazip.com, this curl request has to go out through the 15.250 gateway.

How can I get the external IP of 15.250 whilst using 15.1 for the majority of traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
route add ident.me gw <15.250. gateway>
route add icanhazip.com gw <15.250.gateway>
```

Comment: Looks promising, I'll give that a go

Comment: Additional note: This answer worked. My next issue was that sending SSH in via the accessible gateway caused packets to exit via the high bandwidth gateway. I had to do some packet marking firewall voodoo to resolve this